# Getting value of attribute specified in JPA annotation

Tags: java, jpa, annotations

Assuming that I have some entity with a field annotated as follows:

```
@Column(name="title", length=255)
private String title;
```

how could I get the value of the 'length' attribute with Java?

Comment: you can go with reflections. But why do you want to do that, as the JPA handles it well when working with the DB Schema?

Comment: I want to perform some costume validation on several fields and I want to include the length value into the validation message.

Answer (score 1):

[Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/) (the reference implementation of the [Bean Validation](http://beanvalidation.org/) specification) can be used to do this type of validation without implementing your own annotation-based validator. Integration with JPA allows to execute the validation during the persist or update of an entity. It's an Hibernate project, but it can be used with other JPA providers like EclipseLink.

Answer (score 1):

Using reflection try something like this.

```
Class<?> cls = Class.forName(name);
Annotation ety = cls.getAnnotation(Column.class); 
int value1 = a.length();
```

Although this can be done with the code above. I don't recommend use reflections to do this at all.

Try to use JSR-303 and javax.validation.constraints, there are pretty easy to use.